# How to pass data to other page and submit form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have two pages /search and /form, On the first page there is a simple search form

```
<form class="example1">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

On the second page I have a form

```
<form class="example2">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Searchterm" name="search">
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Is it possible to add click event on first page with AJAX request that when user write a search term and click on search button ,the given search term is going to pass to second page and the form there is going to be submitted?

Comment: Why you don't put both forms in one page and show second form when button click? However you can store data of first form in local stored and using them in another page.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `socket.io` if you want to make the second form submitted by the action of the first one. Because http is stateless and without socket connection, there is no way for server to inform the second page that the first form was submitted (nor form data for that matter). Socket connection could be easily made by `node.js` and `socket.io`. Refer to: https://socket.io/docs/